# json data not assigning to variable

Tags: php, jquery, json

Here is my code:

```
    var lastStampAlpha = 0;
    var lastStampBravo = 0;
    var lastStampCharlie = 0;
    var url = localPath + 'app/data/get-messages-id/resource/null';
    jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data){     
        lastStampAlpha = data.alpha;
        lastStampBravo = data.bravo;
        lastStampCharlie = data.charlie;
    });
```

Here is my JSON data;

```
    {"alpha":"60","bravo":0,"charlie":0}
```

When I try to use lastStampAlpha after assigning `data.alpha` to it, it is not using the JSON data I am trying to assign these variables to. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log( data )`?

Comment: Try opening developer tools and doing a `console.log(data)` inside of the callback. Also, with developer tools, watch the ajax request in the network tab. It is possible the callback isn't being called because of an error. That callback is for "success". When an error happens "success" will not be called.

Comment: How do check it? You aware `getJSON` is async, right?

Comment: interesting. what happens if you use a nemed function instead a anonym function ?

Comment: Thats probably what is happening. When you call getJSON, you are doing an async call. This means, the lines after the block jQuery.getJSON will run before the result becomes available. So, what you need to do is access that inside the block by using a function

Comment: @JoseAreas How do I accomplish this? Can you write an answer assisting me in how to do this?

Comment: I did it already. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You must be sure that you only try and access your variables once the callback has fired.

The callback is the function within the getJSON method.

Make sure that whatever function uses those variables is executed from the callback AFTER you have assigned the values to your variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing:

```
     var lastStampAlpha = 0;
        var lastStampBravo = 0;
        var lastStampCharlie = 0;
        var url = localPath + 'app/data/get-messages-id/resource/null';
        jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data){     
            lastStampAlpha = data.alpha;
            lastStampBravo = data.bravo;
            lastStampCharlie = data.charlie;
        });
Alert(lastStampAlpha);
```

the message will be 0.

If you are doing:

```
 var lastStampAlpha = 0;
    var lastStampBravo = 0;
    var lastStampCharlie = 0;
    var url = localPath + 'app/data/get-messages-id/resource/null';
    jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data){     
        lastStampAlpha = data.alpha;
        lastStampBravo = data.bravo;
        lastStampCharlie = data.charlie;
        useVariables();
    });
function useVariables(){
  Alert(lastStampAlpha);
}
```

The message will be 60.

Comment: Can you make this answer in a more functional way? I need it to assign the variables and then have me access them and have the values in place.

Comment: It is the second block. You first assign the variables and use it inside function useVariables(). is that what you mean?

Comment: i need the values before continuing execution of the script. so, i cannot continue the script until these values are assigned.

Comment: You cant. Because the ajax request is still being processed. You need to wait. the way of wait is use the function block

Comment: Upvoting: good answer, you seem to be the only who understood the initial question correctly ;)

Comment: So the script wont continue until after calling useVariables?

Comment: No. The script will continue. But, the ajax request is running in paralel. Thats why in the first block the alert will be 0. Because the script will move forward. But, the function inside getJSON will run only after the ajax request returns. Did you get it? The function inside getJSON block is a call back. By this I mean, will be called when the ajax requests returns.

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery.when(getMessageIds()).done(function(){})

 function getMessageIds(){
    var url = localPath + 'app/data/get-messages-id/resource/null';
    return jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data){      
        lastStampAlpha = data.alpha;
        lastStampBravo = data.bravo;
        lastStampCharlie = data.charlie;
    });     
}
```